# canvas js pie chart is not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas

i am trying to show a pie char on my website i pick some code from a website but it's not working

```
$dataPoints = array(
    array("label"=> "Food + Drinks", "y"=> 590),
    array("label"=> "Activities and Entertainments", "y"=> 261),
    array("label"=> "Health and Fitness", "y"=> 158),
    array("label"=> "Shopping & Misc", "y"=> 72),
    array("label"=> "Transportation", "y"=> 191),
    array("label"=> "Rent", "y"=> 573),
    array("label"=> "Travel Insurance", "y"=> 126)
);

?>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script>
window.onload = function () {

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    exportEnabled: true,
    title:{
        text: "Average Expense Per Day  in Thai Baht"
    },
    subtitles: [{
        text: "Currency Used: Thai Baht (฿)"
    }],
    data: [{
        type: "pie",
        showInLegend: "true",
        legendText: "{label}",
        indexLabelFontSize: 16,
        indexLabel: "{label} - #percent%",
        yValueFormatString: "฿#,##0",
        dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
    }]
});
chart.render();

}
```

[this is source code link from where i had taken this](https://canvasjs.com/php-charts/animated-chart/)

no result is coming

Comment: Check browser console for errors

Comment: console is not showing any error

Comment: can you include the entire code?

Comment: this code is my entire code only

Comment: You have a PHP server right? Check my answer, it works correctly just using frontend technology

Comment: but i need values from backend not statically so how can i join database value with js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in your backend because if you substitute the `$dataPoints` by a javascript array, it works correctly.

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var dataPoints = [{'label': 'Food Drinks', 'y': 590}, {'label':'Acttivites', y:251}];
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        animationEnabled: true,
        exportEnabled: true,
        title:{
            text: "Average Expense Per Day  in Thai Baht"
        },
        subtitles: [{
            text: "Currency Used: Thai Baht (฿)"
        }],
        data: [{
            type: "pie",
            showInLegend: "true",
            legendText: "{label}",
            indexLabelFontSize: 16,
            indexLabel: "{label} - #percent%",
            yValueFormatString: "฿#,##0",
            dataPoints: dataPoints
        }]
    });
chart.render();
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>  

</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: currently php values are static once it will show result properly then i will add backend

Comment: Check what is your server returning, it should be the same format than the `dataPoints` variable that I defined in the code snippet

Comment: its returning this [{"label":"Food Drinks","y":590},{"label":"Activities and Entertainments","y":261},{"label":"Health and Fitness","y":158},{"label":"Shopping & Misc","y":72},{"label":"Transportation","y":191},{"label":"Rent","y":573},{"label":"Travel Insurance","y":126}]

Comment: Then you should give us more information because as you can see, if you run my code snippet is working fine but it doesn't seem to work fine for you. What is your html? Are you adding the chart js library? Do you get any error in the console?

Comment: thank you for help i had copied your js code and use php code with it now its working